# Not allowed to load local resources

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I try to link my html page to my javascript files in my express app, I get the error above in my developer tools. 
I am running this in an express app with an hbs rendering engine on my local machine. 
The code snippet looks like this

html

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///public/javascripts/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="/javascript" src="file:///public/javascripts/receiver.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///public\javascripts\jquery-2.2.4.min.map"></script>
```

this is the part from app.js that sets the view engine

```js
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

and when I check the developer tools, I get this console error

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///public/javascripts/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.js
>   (index)
>   :1 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///public/javascripts/receiver.js
>   (index)
>   :1 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///public/javascripts/jquery-2.2.4.min.map

Why does the program not access my javascripts?

Comment: You need a webserver, you can't run your website of the `file://` protocol.

Comment: but if I remove it I get a 404 error

Comment: you need to post your express node code so we can see how you have configured your webserver to read your static files.

Comment: @Garuuk Other than setting the view engine to hbs (see edit above), I haven't edited the express file at all

Comment: Again, you can't use a `file://` protocol, you'll end up with same-origin errors. If you're running a webserver in Node, just stop using `file://` and your good.

Comment: `GET http://localhost:3000/public/javascripts/receiver.js 
(index):36 GET http://localhost:3000/public/javascripts/jquery-2.2.4.min.map 
(index):34 GET http://localhost:3000/public/javascripts/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.js 404 (Not Found)`
@adeneo I got rid of the file:// and now I get this

Comment: Now it can't find the files, which is an improvement, and either means the files aren't there, or you're missing a static routing in your Node app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot open local file - Chrome: Not allowed to load local resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007243/cannot-open-local-file-chrome-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First.

Do not load files with **file://**. Just enter the relative path.
Do not load javascript source maps via the script tag. 
You can add this line at the and of the javascript file: 
`//# sourceMappingURL=/path/to/script.js.map`

Second.

You have this little line of code in you express app: `app.use(express.static('public'));`. If not, add it.
The server knows the public path. So you don´t have to write `public/`

If this is your structure:

- server.js
- public/

  - index.html
  - javascripts/
  - receiver.js
  - jquery/

    - jquery-2.2.4.min.js

Write this into your html or handlebars file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/receiver.js"></script>
```